# Get product table from category

Tags: laravel

I'm learning laravel and I have different products in different tables as there are different specifications, so I need separate tables for different category products.

I'm using a package - hasManyOfDescendants however I need to dynamically change the DedicatedSever being unique to the catecory ID

I'm using recursive relations to loop through each category, but now I need to attach my table relation depending of the category id.

How can I pass dynamically the right ID to attach or join to the correct table?

I need to swap out **DedicatedServer** with a dynamic category eg: **Cloud Servers**, **Colocation** etc depending on the category ID

**Controller**

```
return view('marketplace.categories.show', [
   'results' => Category::find($categoryId)->with('servers')->get()
]);
```

**Model**

```
public function servers()
{
    return $this->hasManyOfDescendants(DedicatedServer::class);
}
```

Comment: ```return $this->hasMany(DedicatedServer::class);```

Comment: I'm using a package - hasManyOfDescendants, I need DedicatedServer to be unique depending on the ID category being selected

Comment: do you mean [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)?

Comment: I think your question is a little unclear can you make an example of what you want to do?